# How to remove linux from bootable partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mbr

I have linux mint which I don`t need, besides my ubuntu. It resides on bootable partition. How do I remove it without destroying mbr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Boot to ubuntu.
2. Format your bootable partition with gparted.
3. In gparted set the bootable flag again to the formatted partition.
4. Run `sudo update-grub` to reinstall grub.

Explanation: As there is no mint, grub won't detect the kernel, but it will reinstall itself to mbr with ubuntu kernel.

If you messed up everything and want to correct things. Boot a live cd and install boot-repair

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && sudo boot-repair
```

[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to re-install grub. Boot Ubuntu and run

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```